# How to get onchange callback on radio buttons, but only the one that was SET

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button, onchange

I have a group of radio buttons with the same name, but different values. I'd like to do something like:

```
$("#langs").on("change", "[name=locale]", myfunction);
```

This works, but when I click on a new radio button myfunction gets called twice: once for the "old" radio button that is automatically getting unchecked, and once for the new one I'm clicking on.

changing onchange to onclick is not a solution, because I use it with jquery-mobile and it wraps the inputs with label, so the label is getting clicked, not the input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `$(this)` as an argument to `myfunction` and then inside `myfunction` check if the radio button is checked

`$("#langs").on("change", "[name=locale]", function() { myfunction($(this)); } );`

```
function myfunction(elem) {
    if(elem.is(':checked')) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but I had to do $(elem).is(':checked') to get this to work

Answer (score 6):

Does this work for you? Following the [jQM Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/radiobuttons/events.html)

- [Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/FhcrK/)
- [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/FhcrK/1/) ( fun )

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page"> 
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Choose a language:</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="langs" id="english-lang" value="en" />
        <label for="english-lang">English</label>
        <input type="radio" name="langs" id="korean-lang" value="ko" />
        <label for="korean-lang">Korean</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>​
```

JS:

```
$("input[name=langs]:radio").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
    console.log('Lang: '+$(this).val());

    // Call function here
});
```

Comment: .bind() is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, and the preferred method for binding events is .on() (straight from the doc).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't have any restriction to use onclick evente with jquery in a label. If you have an id, you can use it.
Let's say you have the following html:

```
<label for="foo" id="whatever1">foo</label><input type="radio" name="radiogroup_0" value="foo" >
<label for="bar" id="whatever2">bar</label><input type="radio" name="radiogroup_1" value="bar" >
```

In you jquery you might add:

```
$('#whatever1').click(
  function(){
    //paste your code inside
  }
);
```

Same for the other radio button's label

```
$('#whatever1').click(
  function(){
    //paste your code inside
  }
);
```

Hope this helps.
Luis M.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
     <input type="radio" name="langs" id="first" value="1" onchange="myfunction();"/>
     <label for="first">First</label>
     <input type="radio" name="langs" id="second" value="2" onchange="myfunction();"/>
     <label for="second">Second</label>
     </fieldset>
</div>
```

And then:

```
function myfunction(){
    if($("#langs option:selected")){
    //do something, for example
        alert($("#langs option:selected").text());
    }
}
```

This should call the function only once as it is **contained** within the element that needs uses it.